# Parametrized Java enum

Tags: java, enums, enumeration, generic-collections

How to parameterize one or more `enum` values in Java?

I have 3 very similar `enum`'s:
`ActiveStateGreenRed`, 
`ActiveStateGreenOrange` and
`ActiveStateGreenYellow`.

How to make "generic" `enum` (let's call it `ActiveState`) and "inherited" `enum`'s:

ActiveStateGreenRed    = ActiveState(STATE_COLOR.RED)

ActiveStateGreenOrange = ActiveState(STATE_COLOR.ORANGE)

```
public enum ActiveStateGreenRed {
    INACTIVE(false, STATE_COLOR.RED), //the only difference between enums
    ACTIVE(true, STATE_COLOR.GREEN);

    private final Boolean value;
    private final STATE_COLOR color;

    private ActiveStateGreenRed(Boolean value, STATE_COLOR color) {
        this.value = value;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Boolean toValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public STATE_COLOR toColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want separate enums because you need the type safety (for, say, restricting values passed to a method), or do you want separate enums so you have them efficiently grouped?

Answer (score 1):

`enum`s cannot be inherited. You could do something similar like this:

```
public enum ActiveState {
  INACTIVE_RED(false, STATE_COLOR.RED), //the only difference between enums
  ACTIVE_RED(true, STATE_COLOR.RED),

  INACTIVE_GREEN(false, STATE_COLOR.GREEN),
  ACTIVE_GREEN(true, STATE_COLOR.GREEN);

  ...
}
```

Or, go the "classic" pre-enum way:

```
public final class ActiveState {

  public final static ActiveState ACTIVE_RED = new ActiveState( true, STATE_COLOR.RED );

  public final static ActiveState ACTIVE_GREEN = new ActiveState( true, STATE_COLOR.GREEN );

  ...

  private final Boolean value;
  private final STATE_COLOR color;

  private ActiveState(Boolean value, STATE_COLOR color) {
    this.value = value;
    this.color = color;
  }

}
```

In general, a class with a (package) private constructor of which only predefined, constant instances are provided can be made much like an `enum`. And you can have inheritance hierarchies with these classes.